# Is there a way to restrict who can assign backlogs to iterations in VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I tried looking through the documentation with no luck.

I also went through the permissions at various levels and couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to do this. There is already a feature request relate to this on VSTS User Voice. Refer to this link for details: [Add "Edit work items in this node" security policy to Iteration in Team System](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037755-add-edit-work-items-in-this-node-security-policy)